# Custom headers in WebRequest NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, http-headers, httpwebrequest, asp.net-core-3.1, argumentexception

I'm trying to perform a web request from the client (NET Core 3.1) to a server. But I'm getting an error when passing custom information in headers.
Please, I would like to know how to pass the information in the header.
Thanks.

My code:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:44351/mycontroller");
var postData = "n=42&s=25";
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.Headers["X‐test"] = "884436999";
```

The exception:

[image]

Comment: maybe the encoding file is wrong, check this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/encodings-and-line-breaks?view=vs-2019

Comment: Does the same error occur if you call the `Add` method (instead of the indexer operator) on the `WebHeaderCollection` ? ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webheadercollection))

Comment: @PeterCsala yes, I got the same error when trying this: request.Headers.Add("X‐test", "884436999");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a little tour at the related source code. In [System.txt](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/System.txt) there is a [row](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/System.txt#L869):

```
net_WebHeaderInvalidHeaderChars=Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters.
```

That means we should look for this `net_WebHeaderInvalidHeaderChars` key in the source code of [WebHeaderCollection](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/WebHeaderCollection.cs):

```cs
//
// CheckBadChars - throws on invalid chars to be not found in header name/value
//
internal static string CheckBadChars(string name, bool isHeaderValue) {

    ...

    if (isHeaderValue) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        // NAME check
        //First, check for absence of separators and spaces
        if (name.IndexOfAny(ValidationHelper.InvalidParamChars) != -1) {
            throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString(SR.net_WebHeaderInvalidHeaderChars), "name");
        }
        
        ...
    }
    return name;
}
```

[This means](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/WebHeaderCollection.cs#L528) that the error is thrown if the provided `name` contains some invalid characters.

The `InvalidParamChars` are defined inside the `Internal` class [like this](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Internal.cs#L799):

```cs
internal static readonly char[]  InvalidParamChars =
    new char[]{
    '(',
    ')',
    '<',
    '>',
    '@',
    ',',
    ';',
    ':',
    '\\',
    '"',
    '\'',
    '/',
    '[',
    ']',
    '?',
    '=',
    '{',
    '}',
    ' ',
    '\t',
    '\r',
    '\n'};
```

So, all you have to do is to make sure that the request header name does not contain any of the not allowed characters.

Comment: @Priscila Did you find the invalid character?